# Strange Virus Infecting My Server

Tags: linux, virus, malware, lamp

I am currently working on a Web App on my dedicated server (LAMP) and it seems like it might be infected with some strange malware/virus of some kind.

When I access some domains on that server (every 5 or 10 mins) it will redirect me to something like this.

[image]

The stranger this is that it does not completely redirect!

The URL of my website is still the same, and if it left alone for me than 10 seconds it will comeback to the site.

I have ran some virus/malware scan on my local site to run out that it's not from the client but indeed from the server.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

EDIT: I just confirmed that the virus is not on the server. I just ran into the same problem going through websites on different servers around the web.

Image explanation:

So basically it's a blank page with the picture I linked in the middle of that page. You can click on it and it will take you to fill out some kind of form.

Comment: If you suspect your infected with malware its best to just to backup the data and wipe the server.  The image you linked to makes no sense please update your question to point to the exact image your talking about.

Comment: If you are being redirected then the client machine is infected not the server.  The solution is the same.  You need to backup the critical data and wipe the system.

Answer (score 1):

DNS Changer viruses running in the DNS server can cause this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking and http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2012-07/09/dns-changer-check-and-fix provide more information to get you started. Comcast locally was hit by one of those viruses this summer, so it's still around.